# Creating multiple threads on the same hardware unit

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, architecture, game-engine

My game uses a multi-threading architecture, with the threads laid out like this:

- Main: responsible for the high-level architecture
- Resources: responsible for asynchronous file I/O
- Network: responsible for blocking network I/O
- Workers: do CPU-intensive jobs

Right now, there are (hardware_threads - 3) worker threads, one for each unused hardware unit, but I'd like to add one more by combining the "Resources" and "Network" threads onto one unit since both threads are going to spend a lot of time idling.

1. Is this possible in C++ with boost::thread?
2. Is this even a worthwhile optimization?

Comment: *"Is this even a worthwhile optimization?"* - probably not.

Comment: std::thread is in the standard. Think about using this.

Comment: std::thread doesn't work properly on Windows systems.  It's functionally the same thing as boost::thread anyways, so if I ever need to the switch over is easy.

Comment: `std::async` is the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, in that this is a bad idea. Having a one thread for one job design sounds simple, but it's really not- particularly when some jobs are heavier than others. Also, you have made not enough threads. Usually you want a couple more than that to account for slack in other threads which aren't running right now.

The fundamental problem here is that you are implementing your own threading backend. This is a bad idea. You need to move to something like TBB, which will deal with all of this stuff for you, and those engineers at Intel spent way, way longer profiling and working on it than you.

As for whether this is a worthwhile optimization, well, probably not. Just make enough workers and keep them loaded, and the resources/network thread which are blocking won't really make much difference.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  I just wanted to know if it was worthwhile at all to squeeze out that extra hardware unit, but I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

Threads are great for distributing work and for avoiding something waiting for something happening that doesn't really matter if we wait right now. So using threads is definitely a decent idea for your design.

As to how many threads you should have, and whether it is "worth" having more or less threads? That's a much trickier question to answer. For CPU intensive threads, there's really no point in having more than there are CPU cores in the system, as you won't get more work done by having further threads [there may still be software architecture reasons to have more threads, but that's usually because the software is getting far too complex, and hopefully you don't get there...]

For things that wait, and thus don't use much CPU, the number of threads are more of "whatever makes it easy to handle in the code" - obviously, having thousands is probably a bad idea, but one or two or three isn't going to make much of a difference. You'll obviously have the same problem with "how do I tell the thread what to do next, and when do I need to wait for the result...", etc. An idle thread doesn't "do" much to system performance - it takes up a small amount of stack memory and an even smaller amount of thread control data, but it's such a small amount that it doesn't really matter if you haven't got huge numbers of them.

In summary, probably "a lot of screaming for very little wool" as the blind man said when he sheared the pig - in other words, lots of work, not much benefit.

Comment: Nah. You need to have more threads because all threads block for small amounts- for example, memory allocations or system calls. It's usually best to have a couple threads ready to run at all times.

Comment: Right, I was referring to threads that do not wait at all (e.g. just spit out a stream of data, and if an item is not used up, it spits out the next one regardless). But yes, if there is ANY kind of waiting involved in any of the threads, then you need more threads than number of available CPU's to ensure full usage of the CPU's.